# is it possible to connect via VNC to a server behind the gateway?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, remote

I'm trying to connect to a server in our school, which is behind another server (named gateway), so connecting to the gateway with running VNC server on the host side and then VNC viewer (like tigerVNC) on the local machine is straightforward and works properly,

I'm wondering how to connect with my local machine to the server which is behind the gateway one.

So briefly:

local machine -> gateway server works!

local machine -> gateway server -> another server is my question!

All the machines are configured with the same VNC and its configuration.

Comment: You're going to have to ask the school IT department. You will not be able to punch your way through unless the gateway is configured to allow you - only your school will know the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several straightforward ways to do this, provided you have access to the remote server to set it up (and assuming your remote server does have internet access)...

1. Reverse-SSH: Essentially, you SSH from the the "remote" device into your "host" device and tell the host to use the existing tunnel to SSH back into the server. (This assumes that your host device is more easily accessible, e.g. a personal computer behind a router/firewall that you have admin privileges over, and a static IP or domain.) From the remote server, you would run: `ssh -fN -R AAAA:localhost:BBBB username@yourMachine-ipaddress` (where AAAA is the port on your host machine, and BBBB is the port on the remote server.)
2. [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com) (or other alternatives): freemium, often open-source websites that will allow you to forward a port on your remote server to a public-facing port on ngrok's server. Once you make a free account on ngrok's website, you can either download ngrok and run it on the server, or reverse-SSH into ngrok with `ssh -R 0:localhost:22 tunnel.us.ngrok.com tcp 22` (this will forward your remote server's port 22 to a randomly assigned port and subdomain on ngrok, e.g. "tcp://AA.tcp.ngrok.io:BBBBB")

Comment: Hi @ETL, Thanks for the answer, what about using X2Go? However, I'm still not confident about how to use it. I think just needs to be installed on the server behind the gateway.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with X2go (you asked about VNC, so I answered specifically about VNC), but I don't think it'll work for the same reason the normal VNC doesn't work; it uses SSH to authenticate, so you still need a direct line to the server's IP:port. I THINK you could use either solution from my answer to use X2go instead of VNC, though. If you like my answer, please mark it as correct!